# change bootstrap colors glyphicons

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the glyphicons from twitter bootstrap 3. Although I've been able to get the icon to work and display as I desire them to, I having one issue that I can't solve. When I click on glyphicon (the thumbs up icon for ex,) I want the icon to change to the color red. For some reason, I can't get the icon color to change in jQuery. I can get the background-color to change so I know my jQuery is working, but not the color of the icon itself. So my questions simply put : How can I change the bootstrap icons colors on click?

Here is the example I'm working on.

bootstrap css for this item. this is the only place I can control color

```
.glyphicon-thumbs-up:before{
    content:"\e125"; 
    color: #7f8c8d; 
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

HTML

```
<a id='liked' href='#' <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up'></span> </a>"
```

I tried using the .css function to work. It works for changing the background-color, but not the color of the icon. I still have to go into the css for that.

jQuery / JavaScript

```
$(".glyphicon").click(function() {

    var socialButton = $(this).attr('id'); // for later


    $(this).css("background-color", "red"); //this works
    $(this).css("color", "red"); //this doesn't

})
```

Since it works only from css, I tried to use the toggleClass function

```
$(".glyphicon").click(function() {

    var socialButton = $(this).attr('id');


    $(this).toggleClass('likedClicked'); // this doesn't

})
```

and I placed this inside of my css to control it

```
.likedClicked {
    content:"\e125"; 
    color: red; 
    opacity: 0.7;
    /*z-index: 10000; Tried changing the z-index on a hunch. didn't work*/
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this at all - just CSS. You can also get rid of your :before styling, and add a custom class to the glyphicon like so:

```
<a href='#' ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up custom"></span></a>
```

and then add styling to `.custom` and then `.custom:active` for the click-styling:

```
.custom{
  color:#7f8c8d;
  opacity:0.7;
}

.custom:active{
  color:red
}
```

**Here is a working example: http://www.bootply.com/IAjESfRw0T**

Comment: you are amazing sir. I've worked on this all day. thanks

Comment: sorry you lost your day, but glad I could help!

Comment: your code works as posted. But if I change the color to anything besides red. Nothing happens. It just stays red as if I haven't saved the file or made changes. Any idea on what that is ? I haven't changed anything else , just the color